# Are offscreen infinitely-looped CSS animations optimized by the browser?

Tags: css, css-animations

**Are there any in-browser optimizations for off-screen infinitely-running CSS animations** (infinite animations which are applied to Elements that are present/displayed within the Document, just not in-view at a certain time)?

*For the sake of a more straight-forward discussion, I will refer to CSS animations that involve only composition: using only transforms and/or opacity.*

---

If we have a **CSS animation**, that has `animation-timing-function: infinite;`, **how is it handled if the animated element is not actually on the screen / in-view**?

There are some known scenarios regarding animations, which are irrelevant to this use case:

- The animation will pause if the browser tab is pushed into the background. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/CSS_JavaScript_animation_performance)
- The animation is ignored if the element is removed from the Document, with something like `display: none;` (can't find a quotable source atm);

---

If the element is simply 'beyond the scroll', and the user can reach it at anytime, during the time the element is off-screen :

- Does the animation run as normal, and has the same consumption, regardless if the element is visible or not?
- Does it run as normal, but because it is not painted, the process itself becomes less expensive? - would make more sense.
- Is the animation paused entirely? - would assume not, as the browser must know what the 'current progress' would have been at the moment the element needs to be painted again.
- Or are there any other in-browser processes which optimize this, when these conditions are met?

---

Any documented answer, or any redirect to some resource, which could shed some light on the matter would be greatly appreciated.

---

This discussion would be relevant in determining if : manually removing infinite animations (for elements that are off-screen) would be a thing to consider, to achieve better performance.

Comment: Interesting question. The animation _could_ however be paused when offscreen, and picked back up based on how long ago it was started when it comes into view. Not sure if thats what happens, just mentioning that it indeed could just keep track of time.

Comment: I believe I heard discussions about it from CSS people. But don't recall the "plan details." When they create the solution I hope it is shared across to the Javascript world; Resources can be saved on the Javascript side by asking the browser if the elements the script is working on is even watchable.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR

As long as the properties we want to animate **do not trigger reflow/repaint**, the animation can be optimized by the browser, which means better performance.

See [off main thread animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/CSS_JavaScript_animation_performance#off_main_thread_animation).